# Converting Javascript to bash

Tags: javascript, jquery, bash, unix, formatting

Ok here is my question this is just a standard javascript functions all it does is when a certain checkbox is clicked it selects all the ones following that proper id match

So what im curious is how do i take this javascript function and make it usable in bash scripting... So i can call this function in my script if that makes sense!

```
echo '<input type=checkbox list=item1> num1'
echo '<input type=checkbox list=item2> num2'
echo '<input type=checkbox list=item3> num3'






$(function(){
  $("#allcb").click(function() {
     var chkBoxes = $("input[id^=cb]");
     chkBoxes.prop("checked", !chkBoxes.prop("checked"));
    }); 
});
```

so I add some basic code. so the cgi file outputs into the html to construct those checkboxes.  now is there anyway to achieve this java-script function even if we don't use it.

Comment: which browser are you using in bash?

Comment: The file im working with is a cgi file that is put into an shtml.  So any browser if that helps

Comment: The JS runs in the Browser on the client. Your cgi-script runs on the server. So maybe the script may modify the markup that is delivered to the client, but it can't trigger any JS in the Browser. What are we talking about? Sessions and user-specific-configs? or what?

Comment: Well it should all be done on the server side so my guess is script is not accepting the markup... But when you access the web page the individual should be able to see it but im lost on how to have the function work inside of cgi if thats even possible? because I have created an entire html page with cgi but just cant figure out how to input functions...

Comment: This function checks boxes in the page being displayed in the browser. What changes *on the server* are you trying to have those boxes represent? What is your **actual** goal here?

Comment: The actual goal is inside my cgi file i have checkboxs that when one is selected i need it to check all the others with the same why this function does.  So is it not possible to have javascript function like this inside of cgi?  The CGI file is basically filling in the middle of my html file, thats why i am trying to make a function that will check those boxes..

Comment: @NewEffect, I think you don't get the duality of client and server (even if they run on the same machine). The one and only thing the client (aka browser) can do is calling a url and requesting some data (and/or sending some). And the only thing the server can do is answering the request made by the client. There is NO WAY that the client can execute sth. on the server or vice versa, they can only chat with each other.

Comment: @NewEffect to achieve this you have to create some kind of "database" or file or cache or sth. to keep the state of each checkbox between two calls. Then you have to provide an API/url where the JS can call and tell the backend that some checkbox has been toggled. Now when the JS is executed it has to do this call to the backend. And you have to extend your cgi-script so it uses this state and modifies the markup before sending it to the client, so that the particular checkboxes have the checked-attribute set.

Comment: why do you need server side state management? why can't we just use javascript? when user clicks a checkbox, the ones following that can be toggled just with javascript.

Comment: @Thomas makes sense I am by no means an expert here im just trying to figure a way around this it doesnt have to be javascript, most of the cgi is in html so i figured it might be possible so is it even possible to give those boxes kind of a toggle switch? when one is click it checks all the sub-heading boxes cause, they can just select them all thereselves but i would like the main one to toggle its subheadings....

Comment: @ShishirArora, because as far as I understand NewEffect, this is what he is asking for. Tthat on click of a checkbox this doesn't only change on this particular client, for this particular page-request, but kind of in the cgi-script that delivers the markup. For me this is state.

Comment: @NewEffect, am I right, with my understanding of your problem/intentions?

Comment: @Thomas It will not change in the cgi script basically the cgi script will spit out the information into html... so it only see that all boxes are toggled when they submit what they have clicked on.  So i guess when the client opens the page they will see all the checkboxes and be able to select the boxes they want and click submit and then the server will spit back the information they are looking for.. does that clear it up any lol sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Thomas yes, you r right. I think he just want's to construct html page with bash scripting. This page will have html tags + script tags and it will run on client only. further on form submit  rest  services will be needed on server.